# apex 23.1 Configuration of email on apex.oracle.com Free account

Tags: oracle-apex

When I execute `UTL_MAIL.send` on `apex.oracle.com`. it show me this error

> PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_MAIL.SEND' must be declared

I know my grants is missing but how can I do my grants on this package at apex.oracle.com (Free account).

How to configure email on apex.oracle.com?

I m using apex 23.1 at todays date

I just have tried to send email from apex.oracle.com, I check websites but not got a good solution yet

Answer (score 1):

This is my **apex.oracle.com** account's application. I created a page

1. with a button
2. beneath it, there's a process (I removed unnecessary properties from the screenshot)

- make sure to turn the **Send Immediately** property **ON**

  - help says:

  > Specify whether this email is sent immediately. This will also send all emails currently in the Oracle APEX email queue table. **By default**, Oracle APEX stores unsent email messages in a table and **periodically delivers them** for better system performance.

  which means that you might wait *forever* (OK, not really, but - you won't receive mail that soon) if you don't enable it

3. Result (my Gmail inbox):

   [image]

Therefore, yes - you **can** send email from apex.oracle.com.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't try that myself !

Comment: So that I could do it for you, @Koen :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apex mail send mail process
[image]

or you can use apex In-build function APEX_MAIL

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_mail.htm#AEAPI341

Comment: It not working in both ways, (either from interface or from database procedure), As UTL_MAIL is not available. Network ACL is also no allowing to send email on apex.oracle.com.  I know the grants are missing and we need to add procedure in ACL but how can I grant procedure at apex.oracle.com?